# How to specify fully identified database qualifier in Google Spanner

Tags: google-cloud-platform, command-line-interface, google-cloud-spanner

https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/spanner/databases/execute-sql says that the database positional parameter in an execute-sql command can be "ID of the database or fully qualified identifier for the database".

I can't find the syntax for such a fully qualified identifier. Looked/searched anywhere I could think of in the documentation.

Trying standard separators (slash, dot, colon, etc) produces random error messages.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fully qualified name of a Cloud Spanner database takes the following format:

`projects/<project-id>/instances/<instance-id>/databases/<database-id>`

Comment: This is working :-) thx. But it's only half an answer, for extra 50% tell me where you found this..

Comment: Does 'in my head' count ;-) Sorry, I work a lot with the Java client libraries, and there are a lot of references to it there, but I guess it might be less obvious from the other documentation. For what it's worth: The REST API uses the same format (https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/reference/rest#rest-resource:-v1.projects.instances.databases)

Answer (score 1):

Here is an overview over resource names: https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/full-resource-names. This indicates that the resource name (is this synonymous with identifier?) should be of the format: **//spanner.googleapis.com/projects/project-id/instances/instance-id**

Comment: ) gcloud  spanner databases execute-sql //spanner.googleapis.com/projects/my-project/instances/my-instances/databases/my-database --sql "SELECT count(1) FROM some_table"                                                                                  ❯❯❯

ERROR: (gcloud.spanner.databases.execute-sql) Error parsing [database].
The [database] resource is not properly specified.
Failed to find attribute [instance]. The attribute can be set in the following ways:
- provide the argument [--instance] on the command line
- set the property [spanner/instance]

Comment: Ok I tested this out. This works for me:
gcloud spanner databases execute-sql testdb --instance test --sql "SELECT * FROM villetest"

Obviously this just looks for the test instance in my current project. When I try to add the full instance name it says "the requested URL <code>/v1/projects/tasklist-278604/instances///spanner.googleapis.com/projects/tasklist-278604/instances/test/databases/testdb/sessions?alt=json</code> was not found on this server. " 

So probably you need to set the project with gcloud config and then just use the instance id, not the full name?

Comment: Or you can use --project to set the project in your gcloud command.

Comment: Thanks, I was aware of that way, but I wanted to check something with the fully qualified name..

Comment: Yeah I guess I misunderstood the question a bit. I am not sure if the resource IDs are really exhaustively described anywhere tbh.